# how can I scrap data from reddit (in bash)

Tags: bash, wget, reddit

I want to scrap titles and date from http://www.reddit.com/r/movies.json in bash

wget -q -O - "http://www.reddit.com/r/movies.json" | grep -Po '(?<="title": ").*?(?=",)' | sed 's/\"/"/'

I have titles but I don't know how to add dates, can someone help?

Comment: The URL doesn't exist. Missing name of subreddit? You probably want `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

> wget -q -O - "http://www.reddit.com/r/movies.json" | grep -Po
> '(?<="title": ").*?(?=",)' | sed 's/"/"/'

As extension suggest it is JSON (`application/json`) file, therefore `grep` and `sed` are poorly suited for working with it, as they are mainly for using regular expressions. If you are allowed to install tools, `jq` should be handy here. Try using your system package manager to install it, if it succeed you should get pretty printed version of `movies.json` by doing

```
wget -q -O - "http://www.reddit.com/r/movies.json" | jq
```

and then find where interesting values are placed which should allow you to grab it. See [jq Cheat Sheet](https://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/jq) for example of `jq` usage. If you are limited to already installed tools I suggest taking look at [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module of `python`.